# How can I convert from base 5 to base 10?

Tags: c#

How can I convert the number 1234 to its base 10, 194 using code ?

```
string toBase10 = Convert.ToString(1234, 10);
Console.WriteLine(toBase10);
```

Comment: The worst part of this question is that it was provoked because the OP was taking an university exam while posting it. Nice answers, though.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way, use Linq:

```
static int ConvertFromBase5(string number)
{
    return number.Select(digit => (int)digit - 48).Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x * 5 + y);
}
```

Use:

```
Console.Write(ConvertFromBase5("1234"));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public static long FromBase(long value, int @base)
{
    string number = value.ToString();
    long n = 1;
    long r = 0;

    for (int i = number.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        r += n*(number[i] - '0');
        n *= @base;
    }

    return r;
}
```

I made it `long` to handle bigger values. You could make it `int` if you wanted.

You could use it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(FromBase(1234, 5)); // Prints "194"
```

Or if you wanted a string, just use `ToString()` on it.

```
var asString = FromBase(1234, 5).ToString();
```

It won't handle bases above 10 - but you can't hold numbers above base 10 in an `int` or `long` anyway - In fact, it's odd to do that for any base other than 10. Usually you'd use a `string` to avoid accidentally using those numbers as if they were base 10.

Answer (score 0):

Another LINQ solution:

```
static int ConvertFromBase(int num, int @base)
{
    return num.ToString().Reverse()
              .Select((c, index) => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c) * (int)Math.Pow(@base, index))
              .Sum();
}

Console.WriteLine(ConvertFromBase(1234, 5));  // 194
```